# Functions: pass pointer to $con

Tags: php, function, pointers

I'm displaying a relatively "heavy" PHP page. I have several functions that each use a connection to the DB to grab some rows. I've noticed that making a new $con in each function slows things down a lot, so naturally I would like to use the same $con for each function on the page. I tried this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root", "mydb");

function fA($a, $b, &$con = $con)
{}

function fB($a, &$con = $con)
{}
```

You can see I'm trying to pass a pointer to $con for each function, but I get a `syntax error, unexpected $con` for each one. (I could pass $con to the functions whenever I call them but doing it this way I don't have to go back and change every function call, and it looks neater)

Comment: PHP doesn't work like that. `$con` isn't defined at the time you define the function. Just define as `function fA($a, $b, $con)` and the object `$con` will always be passed by reference.

Comment: In other words, you can't get out of passing a parameter at runtime by "pre-defining" a variable in the function prototype. You can define a default with a constant value, but not with a dynamic (variable) value.

Comment: ok so if I call fA(10, 12) he will automatically get $con?

Comment: If you're looking for type hinting, define the argument as `mysqli $con`

Comment: @Juicy No. You need to pass $con as a param, and you should because it makes your code readable.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, thanks, I get it. Just to clarify things, what would be the difference between function fA($a,$b,$con) and function fA($a,$b,&$con). Is it better for performance to pass the pointer or not?

Comment: Defining the reference `&$con` is unnecessary and redundant.  PHP always passes objects by reference, so the `$con` passed into the function will be the exact same object defined outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
global $con;
```

At the beginning of each function's body like so:

```
function fA($a, $b) {
    global $con
    // ...etc...
}
```

But this is generally viewed as a bad practice.

A better approach would be to use dependency injection so that your logic would not be dependent on the kind of storage device given to it. Something along these lines:

```
class LogicExecutor {
    private $con;

    public __construct($con) {
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    public function doTaskOne($a, $b) {
        // you can use $this->con in this scope
    }
}

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'mydb');
$le = new LogicExecutor($con);

$le->doTaskOne('a','b');
```

But even that would couple your code to `mysqli` very tightly. Have you considered an [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library)?

Answer (score 0):

Using global $con is ok, best solution is put the stuff into a class.

If you sticked to your original concept, you should pass $con on every function call.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mydb");
fA("abraca","dabra",$con);
fB("hocus-pocus",$con);

function fA($a, $b, &$con)
{}

function fB($a, &$con)
{}
```

Maybe it's better to use $con as the first parameter.